# Decay to base class

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-traits

Is there a trait that returns the base class of a specific class, with the assumption that there is no multiple inheritance involved? Basically something like:

```cpp
struct Base
{

};

struct Derived : public Base
{

};

struct DerivedDerived : public Derived
{

};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<base<DerivedDerived>::type,Derived>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<base<Derived>::type,Base>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<base<Base>::type,Base>);
// with levels
static_assert(std::is_same_v<base<0,DerivedDerived>::type,Base>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<base<1,DerivedDerived>::type,Derived>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<base<2,DerivedDerived>::type,DerivedDerived>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<base<0,Derived>::type,Base>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<base<1,Derived>::type,Derived>);
```

Comment: You would have to inject that information yourself, something like `struct Derived : public GetBase<Base> {};`

Comment: @super Yeah, the idea was not to have to, otherwise, yes I can write type traits or do some hackery with crtp.

Answer (score 5):

Nope. You can test whether a given type inherits from a given other type with `std::is_base_of`, but not ask for the base type outright. That is, until C++ gets static reflection sometime in the future.

Comment: "Sometime in the future" meaning "scheduled no earlier than 2026" according to recent estimates I believe.

Comment: @MaxLanghof :( -